# Cache SpriteSheets in EaselJS

Tags: javascript, caching, html5-canvas, easeljs, sprite-sheet

How can I cache SpriteSheets in EaselJS? I have a Sprite object and when I use `user.hero.cache(0, 0, 30, 40);` it stops playing animation (probably because I'm just caching the current frame, not the entire SpriteSheet image). So how can I cache it?

**Here's my relevant EaselJS code:**

```
data = {
    images: ["Graphics/hero.png"],
    frames: {
        width: 30,
        height: 40
    },
    animations: {
        stand: 0,
        run: [1, 2, "runLoop", 0.15],
        runLoop: [3, 7, true, 0.15],
        jump: [8, 10, "happy", 0.5],
        happy: 11,
        fall: 12,
        stopFalling: [13, 14, "stand", 0.2],
        almostFalling: [16, 19, true, 0.1]
    }
};
user.hero.spriteSheet = new createjs.SpriteSheet(data);
user.hero = new createjs.Sprite(user.hero.spriteSheet, "stand");
user.hero.name = "hero";
user.hero.x = user.hero.safeX = 40 * 3;
user.hero.y = user.hero.safeY = 0;
user.hero.offset = 4;
user.hero.regX = user.hero.offset + 2;
user.hero.regY = user.hero.offset;
user.hero.width = 30 - (user.hero.offset * 2) - 10;
user.hero.height = 40 - (user.hero.offset * 2);
user.hero.xvel = user.hero.yvel = 0;
user.hero.cache(0, 0, 30, 40); // <--- This is the problem.
movableObjContainer.addChild(user.hero);
movableObj.push(user.hero);
```

**Without cache:**

[image: without cache]

**With cache:**

[image: with cache]

I've tried caching the `data.image` or `user.hero.spriteSheet` too, without success.
Is there any way to cache the SpriteSheet without compromising its animations?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you cache the sprite, you are saving off how it looks at that instant.

Can you explain why you want to cache it? The only reason I can think of to cache it would be to apply filters. Each time you cache it, the contents are drawn to an off-screen canvas, which is then drawn in place of it. This makes a lot of sense if you have complex content, like a container or graphics, which do not change, but with the spritesheet, it means you are creating a new bitmap to draw a bitmap. The spritesheet itself is a great way to be filesize, network, and GPU-optimzed, so re-caching it is basically negating all those benefits.

If you want to cache anyways, you will need to re-cache it, or call `updateCache()` every time it changes. Here is an example using the ticker.

```
createjs.Ticker.on("tick", function() {
    user.hero.updateCache();
    // or
    user.hero.cache(0,0,30,40) 
}, this);
```

Here is a quick demo I did a while back using a few approaches for filters. It provides an example of constant re-caching, as well as an example where the entire spritesheet is cached to apply the filter once, and then that cached version is used for the sprite.
http://jsfiddle.net/lannymcnie/NRH5X/

Comment: But can't I cache the source image instead of the actual frame? Because a spritesheet is actually an image, and at least for Bitmaps, caching increases performance a lot.

Comment: I didn't noticed that your JSFiddle has the answer to my question, and you were caching a bitmap and then using it in `data2` object. This method can increase performance as well as just caching a bitmap does?

Comment: Caching a bitmap is only a good idea if you change it somehow. Caching a sprite each tick will have a huge performance impact, and almost no benefit.

Comment: are you sure that caching a bitmap is only a good idea if you change it? When I don't use caching, even for unchanged bitmaps, there's a **huuuuge** performance impact. And then when I use caches, the performance issues disappear. I don't know if this is true for SpriteSheets too — then I'm currently using the second method in your fiddle to cache an unchanged bitmap and then use it in a SpriteSheet. Do you think this is wrong?

Comment: If you cache a bitmap without changing it, you are just making a new Bitmap, but on a canvas instead of an Image tag. The original will still be in memory, and the new one is both in memory, and also pushed to the GPU.

Comment: Then what's increasing my game's performance is that the new bitmap generated with caching is *"pushed to the GPU"*? Thanks for the help, Lanny, I **really** appreciate it.

Comment: I am not sure. It could be the difference between using a canvas and bitmap? Are you seeing the same increase in all browsers?

Comment: Yes, the performance increase occur in Safari, Google Chrome and Firefox when I cache unchanged bitmaps.

Comment: [**Here's an image of my CPU usage monitor.**](http://i.imgur.com/ADlOeM0.png) The difference isn't that big in the image because I'm using a good processor *(quad-core i7)*, but in lower-end processors the CPU usage without cache is worse.