# Apply a Filter to an animated Sprite in EaselJS

Tags: javascript, easeljs

In EaselJS, I have a `Sprite` that depicts a soldier that can attack (which causes an animation to be played) and that can be poisoned (which causes the unit to turn green via a `ColorFilter`).

However, these actions appear to be incompatible with one another: after I apply the `ColorFilter`, the sprite can no longer animate. This is because a `Filter` requires that its target be cached, which makes the Sprite unable to animate. If I remove the `animation.cache` call, below, then the animation runs but the color filter fails to apply.

How can I apply a filter to a `Sprite` while still allowing it to animate? Can I apply a filter to the underlying spritesheet image, somehow, instead of directly to `Sprite` itself? Would that require the creation of a new `Sprite` every time I wanted to turn the filter on and off?

I have a [fiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/33k21h4d/1/), whose relevant code is included below:

```
var stage = new createjs.Stage("canvas");
createjs.Ticker.addEventListener("tick", handleTick);
function handleTick(event) { stage.update(event); }

var url = "...";
var spriteSheet = new createjs.SpriteSheet({
    images: [url],
    frames: { width:72, height:72 },
    animations: {
        attack:[1,6]
    }
});
var animation = new createjs.Sprite(spriteSheet);
stage.addChild(animation);

attackButton.addEventListener("click", function() {
    animation.gotoAndPlay("attack");
});

poisonButton.addEventListener("click", function() {
    animation.filters = [
        new createjs.ColorFilter(0.5,1,0.5,1,0,0,0,0)
    ];
    animation.cache(0,0,72,72);
});
```

Comment: Strangely enough it seems to play in the background. If you press poison again, its on another frame.

Comment: Moved updating the cache to the update cycle, not sure how that affects performance though: https://jsfiddle.net/33k21h4d/21/

Comment: @Caramiriel Excellent detective work! That does sound pretty crappy for performance, but I realized that I could do the same in a [`change` event listener](https://createjs.com/docs/easeljs/classes/Sprite.html#event_change) that fires only on animation update. For the fiddle, there's no difference, but for my game (where units will spend most their time on screen *not* actively animating) the difference is substantial. The cost of recaching might be tolerable.

Answer (score 1):

Currently, updating the cache each frame is the best (and easiest option). It is not great for performance though.

You can also filter & cache the spritesheet itself, though its a little more difficult. I answered this question twice before, with [this sample](https://jsfiddle.net/lannymcnie/NRH5X/):

- [Cache SpriteSheets in EaselJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24499486/cache-spritesheets-in-easeljs/24500603#24500603)
- [EaselJS Spritesheet and Bitmap ColorFilterMatrix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48510861/easeljs-spritesheet-and-bitmap-colorfiltermatrix)

Here is some pseudo-code:

```
spritesheet.on("complete", function(e) {
    for (var i=0; i<spritesheet._images.length; i++) {
        // Filter Code Here
        // Then
        spritesheet.images[i] = filteredBitmap.cacheCanvas;
    }
}
```

Hope that helps!